# devoloper drupal manual

Tags: drupal

I am looking for a Tutorial for developers in drupal, I don't know anything about drupal so  I need a tutorial that explain very well,
in main page of drupal I can't find a tutorial who explain since the most basic about it

thanks for the advices!

Answer (score 1):

Here: http://drupal.org/documentation
It's official Drupal documentation. It should be enough for starters.

Answer (score 1):

[This list of books](http://drupal.org/node/1485226) is a good place to start as a developer, but assume that you know PHP. If you just mean sitebuilding, but not coding, try [here](http://drupal.org/node/1485156). I find that often, the more comprehensive approach a book takes (as opposed to sometimes piecemeal info in online docs) can be more supportive for a total beginner.

Answer (score 0):

[Simpletest Tutorial](http://drupal.org/simpletest-tutorial) here.This may helpful

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the [developer docs](http://drupal.org/documentation) are all very good but I find you can't beat a [book](http://www.drupalbook.com/) to work through.

Set yourself small tasks and work through them one at a time. Something like:

1. Install Drupal
2. [Create a new content type](http://lin-clark.com/blog/intro-drupal-7-creating-content-types)
3. Create some pages
4. [Install a ready made theme](http://opennomad.com/drupal-themes/)
5. [Create a theme from scratch](http://www.apaddedcell.com/how-create-drupal-7-theme-scratch)
6. Install some modules

And so on.

Just make little goals and go from there. The learning curve is pretty steep.

If you have any more specific questions, ask them on here on the dedicated [Drupal site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/).